# how to add DNS suffix in mac machine?

Tags: mac

how to add DNS suffix in mac machine?
ex: for abc.xyz.com if i type abc in my mac browser it should load actual url...

Answer (score 7):

System Preferences -> Network -> *Interface* -> Advanced -> DNS. Search domains is on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

it has changed since 2010, on my Monterey OS, it's located in
`System Preferences -> Network -> <Interface> -> Details -> DNS`