# Site is not reachable from my provider

Tags: routing, isp

My ISP is Optus (Melbourne, Australia).

When I visit the site, http://www.ozon.ru, its content loads but the script sourced from (presumably) CDN, http://bundle.ozon.ru/ozon/1.0.6.164/js/bozon.min.1251.js, does not load with the error (in Chrome) `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. The same happens with cURL: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to bundle.ozon.ru port 80: Connection timed out`.

However, the URL is reachable from a proxy in Russia, as well as *some* other locations. For example, test result http://www.syslab.ru/geoping/stat/189124 (Russian) shows the URL reachable from Russia and Germany. https://ping-admin.ru/ shows the URL not reachable from Hong Kong or Singapore, but working from Adelaide, Australia. https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime shows "TCP connection failed" from Hong Kong, but working from Sydney, Australia.

Quite a few online checker tools don't support checking the full *URL*, and the CDN root, http://bundle.ozon.ru, respond with a 403, which translates to a "fail" - see, for example, http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/bundle.ozon.ru.

`traceroute` and `tracepath` stop at `hll-qrator.te0-0-0-9-br02.hkg39.pccwbtn.net` and everything after that times out. However, this is the same for *both* `bundle.ozon.ru` and `ozon.ru`. Only `tcptraceroute` is different:

```
# tcptraceroute ozon.ru
Selected device <snip>, address <snip>, port <snip> for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to ozon.ru (178.248.235.123) on TCP port 80 (http), 30 hops max
 1  <snip>  0.969 ms  0.800 ms  0.960 ms
 2  10.76.0.1  10.450 ms  8.522 ms  8.576 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  211.29.126.145  22.178 ms  22.005 ms  29.970 ms
 7  198.142.139.114  23.104 ms  25.498 ms  25.856 ms
 8  10.139.103.2  22.152 ms  23.059 ms  22.244 ms
 9  10.138.202.254  32.854 ms  23.197 ms  26.711 ms
10  10.139.103.1  27.714 ms  22.571 ms  24.505 ms
11  198.142.139.130  28.411 ms  23.824 ms  22.986 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  BHA-0017.gw1.hkg3.10026.telstraglobal.net (61.14.134.92)  233.936 ms  235.754 ms  242.026 ms
16  ge13-34.br01.hkg04.pccwbtn.net (63.218.1.221)  237.935 ms  236.315 ms  243.099 ms
17  TenGE0-0-0-3.br02.hkg39.pccwbtn.net (63.223.20.49)  242.065 ms  238.264 ms  240.253 ms
18  hll-qrator.te0-0-0-9-br02.hkg39.pccwbtn.net (63.222.45.74)  136.004 ms  135.859 ms  136.539 ms
19  178.248.235.123 [open]  238.349 ms  237.518 ms  240.153 ms
```

---

```
# tcptraceroute bundle.ozon.ru
Selected device <snip>, address <snip>, port <snip> for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to bundle.ozon.ru (185.73.192.4) on TCP port 80 (http), 30 hops max
 1  <snip>  1.611 ms  0.816 ms  1.713 ms
 2  10.76.0.1  9.794 ms  7.843 ms  7.826 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  211.29.126.133  25.020 ms  30.168 ms  21.776 ms
 7  198.142.139.114  25.573 ms  22.721 ms  22.908 ms
 8  10.139.103.2  24.762 ms  22.015 ms  22.847 ms
 9  10.138.202.254  23.269 ms  22.306 ms  22.372 ms
10  10.139.103.1  21.830 ms  21.439 ms  21.137 ms
11  198.142.139.130  20.866 ms  22.729 ms  21.092 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  BHA-0017.gw1.hkg3.10026.telstraglobal.net (61.14.134.92)  236.923 ms  232.610 ms  235.966 ms
16  ge13-34.br01.hkg04.pccwbtn.net (63.218.1.221)  232.412 ms  234.397 ms  236.296 ms
17  TenGE0-0-0-2.br02.hkg39.pccwbtn.net (63.223.20.53)  237.406 ms  233.631 ms  242.758 ms
18  hll-qrator.te0-0-0-9-br02.hkg39.pccwbtn.net (63.222.45.74)  135.083 ms  134.674 ms  133.454 ms
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
Destination not reached
```

I have contacted ozon.ru tech support, who promised to pass the issue on to the tech team and became silent.

I have also contacted my ISP, Optus, who promised to pass the issue on to the tech team and became silent.

Summary: The site works for some ISPs but not others; whose fault is this and how do I [make someone] fix it?

Update: The address I get for `bundle.ozon.ru` (185.73.192.4) is the same on all the test sites, and I am using Google DNS.

Update: I have sent an email to the technical contact listed for 63.222.45.74. This got me a ticket number, but no resolution yet.

Update: The issue is now resolved and everything loads properly. I still don't know who was at fault or if my complaints helped.

Comment: You can't make anybody fix it, as it is a routing issue outside of your control. Looks like `63.222.45.74` is a misconfigured router. You could try emailing OrgTechEmail:  usnoc@pccwglobal.com.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the suggestion, tried that, will update if I get a reply.

Comment: You could also try a Dns Proxy. To see if this will work to allow you to access the website.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I get the correct IP address (try it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a DNS problem or your ISP is blocking this website.

You could try to [configure different DNS in your PC manually](https://superuser.com/questions/199344/how-to-add-dns-suffix-in-mac-machine). You could get a list of DNS [here](http://public-dns.info/).

If it doesn't work probably your ISP is blocking this website. Here the only way to access to the website is throught a VPN to a place where it's authorized.

Comment: I get the correct address for the website - it's the same from every server check tool.